# Does malloc + fork create a memory leak?

Tags: unix, malloc, fork

1. Parent process does malloc()
2. fork
3. parent modifies the allocated block
4. CoW kicks in and creates one copy of the modified block while keeping the old copy in place
5. The child doesn't know or care about the parent's stuff and doesn't call free() on its copy of it
6. Memory leak!

Am I correct? Am I wrong? If the latter what does actually happen?

Comment: CoW is called in the child only when it tries to modify the contents of the memory block. The child process is an exact copy of the parent (with some things that are not inherited, see `man fork`). It's up to the programmer to call `free()` before terminating the child. Tho the cleanup at the program's end will do it, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither the `malloc()` nor the `fork()` creates a leak — so I suppose you're wrong.

The parent has its own copy of the allocated block.  It may do as it wishes with it.  The child has its own copy of the allocated block.  It too may do as it wishes with it.  If the child ignores the block, it is not a leak (yet).  If the child blithely tramples a pointer, or returns from a function that holds the only pointer to the allocated memory without releasing it first, that would lead to a leak.  But it isn't the `fork()` or the `malloc()` that's at fault.

Remember, the same code is running after the `fork()` — the major difference between the processes is the PID and the return value from `fork()`.  Everything else (almost everything else — see the POSIX specification of [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) for the details) is the same.  So, if the code leaks, that's a bug introduced by the programmer — it is not the fault of either `malloc()` or `fork()`.

Note that if the child uses one of the `exec*()` family of functions, all the allocated memory from the original process is released.  The new process gets new memory allocated.  Similarly, if the child exits, then the memory will be released.  There isn't a long-term risk of the O/S losing track of memory.

Comment: In short: If child doesn't care about a block allocated by the parent if should free() it. Otherwise, the child's copy of the block will linger in RAM till the child terminates or exec is called. Correct?

Comment: Yes; that's a pretty accurate summary of things, although it glosses over the fact that freed memory (returned via `free()`) is usually left available for reuse by another call to `malloc()` rather than being returned to the o/s.